# How to execute Python inline from a bash shell

Tags: python, shell, inline, execution

Is there a Python argument to execute code from the shell without starting up an interactive interpreter or reading from a file? 
Something similar to:

```
perl -e 'print "Hi"'
```

Comment: `-c` is the second option described in the `man` page.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

This works:

```
python -c 'print("Hi")'
Hi
```

From the manual, `man python`:

> ```
>    -c command
>           Specify  the command to execute (see next section).  This termi-
>           nates the option list (following options are passed as arguments
>           to the command).
> ```

Comment: Also useful to remember that you can use `;` to separate statements, e.g., `python -c 'import foo; foo.bar()'`

Comment: Doesn't work for me on python 3.8.`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Hi' is not defined`

Comment: Make sure "Hi" is in quotes.

Comment: Also how do I access a variable in the command

Comment: You can turn on interactive mode with `-i`:

`python -i -c 'a = 5'`

`>>> a`

`5`

Answer (score 39):

Another way is to you use bash redirection:

```
python <<< 'print "Hi"'
```

And this works also with perl, ruby, and what not.

p.s.

To save quote ' and " for  python code, we can build the block with EOF

```
c=`cat <<EOF
print(122)
EOF`
python -c "$c"
```

Answer (score 38):

A '[heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)' can be used to directly feed a script into the python interpreter:

```
python <<HEREDOC
import sys
for p in sys.path:
  print(p)
HEREDOC


/usr/lib64/python36.zip
/usr/lib64/python3.6
/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload
/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Comment: How can redirect the output into a text file (under `bash`)? I am trying to add "`> temp.txt`" after the command and also to use a pipe and other ideas, but the file is zero length.

Comment: OK, figured that out. You need to add the "`> temp.txt`" after the first `HEREDOC` on the first line in your example., i.e., do: "`$ python <<HEREDOC > temp.txt`"

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the [`e` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/e)

eg.

```
$ python -me 1 + 1
2
```

Comment: Interesting. But you need to have an extra install.

Comment: Useless unless you've already run `pip install e`.  For a standard python install, this produces the error: `No module named e`.