# How can I run inline Python code in a command-line shell?

Tags: python, shell, command-line

In a shell, I can execute AppleScript command-line code like so:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to activate"
```

Is the same thing possible in Python, e.g.:

```
python --execute "print('hello world!')"
```

Comment: `man python` will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute Python inline from a bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908236/how-to-execute-python-inline-from-a-bash-shell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work for you!

```
python -c 'print("Hi")'
```

Probably a duplicate of [How to execute Python inline from a bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908236/how-to-execute-python-inline-from-a-bash-shell)