# How to run python code inside github workflow?

Tags: python, github, github-actions, cicd

I've the below GitHub workflow where I need to run python code to get the token but after the steps are ran I'm getting error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'authlib'" I have installed the required dependency. Works fine when I run locally please can someone help me

```
- name: Get Token
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install requests-oauthlib
          python -c "from authlib.integrations.requests_client import OAuth2Session;"
          if __name__ == '__main__':
           from authlib.integrations.requests_client import OAuth2Session

          token_endpoint = "https://example.com"

          client_id = "********"
          client_secret = "******"

          session = OAuth2Session(client_id, client_secret)
          session.fetch_token(token_endpoint)
          access_token = session.token["access_token"]

          print(access_token)
```

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908236/how-to-execute-python-inline-from-a-bash-shell

Comment: Your also need another dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Please install Authlib package. https://pypi.org/project/Authlib/

```
pip install Authlib
```

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm!!