# Bash running python inline in shell script still not working

Tags: python, windows, bash

I am on Windows and using GitBash to run shell scripts in bash that run python scripts.

I'm trying to run python inline in a bash shell script using the answer from [How to execute Python inline from a bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908236/how-to-execute-python-inline-from-a-bash-shell).

I'm using a specific python environment, and the path is defined with an alias.

This is a file called `.pyalias`:

```
alias mypython='C:/users/name/mypath/python.exe test.sh'
```

This is a file called `test.sh`:

```
# misc notes at top, like a docstring
print("Hello")
# real file will instead say myPyScript.py etc.
```

**Here is the problem:** This is a file called `main_run_all.sh`:

```
# misc notes at top, like a docstring

shopt -s expand_aliases
source ./.pyalias

mypython test.sh

mypython -c print("Hello Again")
```

When I run `sh main_run_all.sh`, it prints "Hello" to the console (good, it is successfully running the `test.sh` script), but then it doesn't run the inline command, returning the following error:

```
test.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: line 8: `mypython -c print("Hello Again")'
```

Comment: You should just forget about aliases. Use a shell function or a script instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the python code in quotes so the shell doesn't try to parse it like shell code:

```bash
mypython -c 'print("Hello Again")' 
# ..........^....................^
```

If you get python code that contains both double and single quotes, quoting can be a real pain. That's the point when you use a quoted here-doc:

```bash
python <<'END_PYTHON'
print("Hello")
print('World')
END_PYTHON
```